# Jenkins - Multibranch Pipeline unexplained failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, multibranch-pipeline

In my pipeline, I make use of readJSON and writeJSON methods of the [Pipeline Utility Step](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/) plugin to read/write files in pipeline stages. **For a normal pipeline everything works great.** However, when I create a "multibranch pipeline", the same pipeline fails. The failure happens when a subsequent stage attempts to read a file, using readJSON, that should have been produced by a previous stage. The curious part is: within one stage, a file that was produced was available to be used by a command (the command `aws ecs register-task-definition` succeeds) **BUT** is not present in the workspace `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/TestPipeline` on the node afterwards.

To focus on the failure, I am only pasting the relevant stages of the pipeline.

```
stage('RegisterTaskDefinition') {
    agent any
    steps {
        sh 'printenv'
        script {            
            def templateFile = env.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH +'/' + TASK_DEF_TEMPLATE
            def taskDefinitionTemplate = readJSON(file: templateFile)

            taskDefinitionTemplate.taskRoleArn = env.TASK_ROLE_ARN
            taskDefinitionTemplate.executionRoleArn = env.EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN
            taskDefinitionTemplate.containerDefinitions[0].image = "NewImage"
            taskDefinitionTemplate.containerDefinitions[0].portMappings[0].containerPort = env.APP_PORT.toInteger()

            taskDefFile = env.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH + '/' + env.TASK_DEFINITION_FILE
            writeJSON(file: taskDefFile, json: taskDefinitionTemplate)

            def registerTaskDefinitionOutput = sh (
            script: "aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://${taskDefFile}",
            returnStdout: true
            ).trim()
            echo "Register Task Def result: ${registerTaskDefinitionOutput}"

            def registerTaskDefOutputFile = env.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH + '/registerTaskDefOutput.json'
            echo "********************************"
            sh 'pwd'
            writeJSON(file: registerTaskDefOutputFile, json: registerTaskDefinitionOutput, pretty: 2)
            echo "********************************${registerTaskDefOutputFile}"
        }
    }
}
stage('CreateTaskSet') {
    agent any
    steps{
        script{
            def registerTaskDefOutputFile = env.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH + '/' + env.REGISTER_TASK_DEF_OUTPUT
            def taskSetTemplateFile = env.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH + '/' + env.TASK_SET_TEMPLATE_FILE
            def taskSetFile = env.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH + '/' + env.TASK_SET_FILE

            def registerTaskDefinitionOutput = readJSON(file: registerTaskDefOutputFile)
            def taskSetTemplateJson = readJSON(file: taskSetTemplateFile)

            taskSetTemplateJson.taskDefinition = registerTaskDefinitionOutput.taskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn
            taskSetTemplateJson.loadBalancers[0].containerPort = env.APP_PORT.toInteger()
            taskSetTemplateJson.loadBalancers[0].targetGroupArn = targetGroupArn

            writeJSON(file: taskSetFile, json: taskSetTemplateJson, pretty: 2)
        }
    }
}
```

To clarify, the `RegisterTaskDefinition` stage succeeds and the failure happens for `CreateTaskSet` stage.

The exception generated is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/TestPipeline/infrastructure/registerTaskDefOutput.json does not exist.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.json.ReadJSONStepExecution.doRun(ReadJSONStepExecution.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.run(AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have the following questions:

1. What explains the behavioral difference b/w the two pipeline types?
2. For a normal pipeline, I can see the files produced by the pipeline under `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/TestPipeline` on the node. For a "multibranch pipeline" that is not the case. What directory is Jenkins using for a "multibranch pipeline"?
3. What logs would help me diagnose the issue?

I am unable to find any documentation that explain this difference in behavior b/w the two pipeline types. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
stage('RegisterTaskDefinition') {
    agent any
```

and

```
stage('CreateTaskSet') {
    agent any
```

This is entirely possible that these two stages run on different agents, since you  have told Jenkins that you want a random agent to run the first stage *and* a random agent to run a second stage. These agents *might* have been the same previously; however there's no requirement they will be the same.

To prevent this, allocate a node early and don't change it:

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stage('1') { ... }
   stage('2') { ... }
}
```

This guarantees that both stages will run on the same agent, so the results that the first stage writes in `${env.WORKSPACE}` will be available to the second one.

Comment: I see your point and it is totally valid. However, in this case, I am running Jenkins in Docker and there is only one agent. I'll try your technique and will update my findings. Thank you.

Comment: Try `echo env.WORKSPACE` at the beginning of both stages to make sure they are the same.

Comment: You are correct. After removing the `agent any` directive, the pipeline works. It appears to be checking out a fresh copy of the repo on both of the stages when the `agent any` is present on the stage. **BUT** this happens only for "multibranch pipeline". This does seem to indicate a behavioral difference b/w the two pipelines. Is this expected?

Comment: Allocation of agent also means allocation of a workspace. I can guess that in a multibranch, it could be allocating once per branch to accommodate situations where two different branches run at the same time on the same node. In a single branch this does not happen.

Comment: If my answer works for you, please don't forget to upvote and mark as accepted, so that other people might use it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @MaratC. I was hoping to learn something from my question, particularly, if there were any logs that would indicate what was happening. Your suggestion helped solve the issue but I don't have concrete answers for my questions. I'll accept your answer, if I don't see any other answers.